# How to deploy a Managed Private Endpoint via ARM template?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-private-link

I have a Synapse Workspace that is getting deployed via ARM (via Ev2). I have manually created a Managed Private Endpoint to a Private Link Service. I need to be able to deploy this connection with the workspace. When I look at the json for the workspace (or when I get az synapse workspace show), I don’t see the endpoint listed, so I am not sure where to start hunting. I don’t find much info online either.

Thanks,
~john